# Call Array key of Map object

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Does anyone knows how to directly call a array key of a Map Object.

As shown in below code, I can **map.get(arr)**, but not **map.get([0, 1, 2, 3])**

```js
const map = new Map()
const arr = [0,1,2,3]
map.set(arr, "I am some number")

map.get(arr) // "I am some number"
map.get([0,1,2,3]) // undefined
```

Comment: you create a new array which does not share the (same) object reference from the used key of the map.

Comment: `map.keys()` will return Iterator where you can achieve you `arr` key. also you can use `forEach`, and this is a link to [Map description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: @alex2007v If you need to iterate for map retrieval, you might as well just use an array.

Comment: @Amadan I know about this, that's why I give a link to Map documentation, because describe all available methods do not worth it.

Comment: @alex2007v: The link has comparison between `Map` and object, and says nothing about `Array`, though. My point was that retrieving from map by iteration will be O(N) just like looking through a list, but with much less overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `Map` compares objects by object identity. `[0, 1, 2, 3] !== [0, 1, 2, 3]` as they are different *objects*, even if they hold the same data.

The nearest thing you can do is to try to convert the array to something you can compare meaningfully:

```js
const map = new Map()
const arr = [0,1,2,3]
map.set(JSON.stringify([0, 1, 2, 3]), "I am some number")

console.log(map.get(JSON.stringify([0, 1, 2, 3])))
```

Comment: Changed the "different but identical" because it sounded like an oxymoron. Not sure if this is better - feel free to review.

Comment: @VLAZ You are right, I should probably have said "equal". "identical... but false when compared by identity" is contradictory. Then again, JavaScript does not have an equality operator capable of comparing arrays, so "equal" is hardly better. I like your wording.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, you have to use the **same** array (as in `map.get(arr)`), not just an equivalent array. Key comparison is like `===` (except that `NaN` matches itself). So just like this shows `false`:

```js
console.log([0, 1, 2, 3] === [0, 1, 2, 3]); // false
```

...using `map.get([0, 1, 2, 3])` is guaranteed not to find anything, because there isn't any entry in the map keyed by that array.

Comment: If you're interested, I cover Map (and Set, WeakMap, and WeakSet) in detail in Chapter 12 of my new book (see my profile for links).

Answer (score 0):

Separate arrays aren't `===` to each other - your `arr` does not refer to the same array container as the `[0,1,2,3]` that you pass to `map.get`. To do something like this, you'd have to iterate over the map's keys and find the one whose values all match:

```js
const map = new Map()
const arr = [0,1,2,3];
map.set(arr, "I am some number")

// Get a reference to the same `arr` whose key you set previously:
const arrKey = [...map.keys()].find(
  key => Array.isArray(key) && JSON.stringify(key) === JSON.stringify([0, 1, 2, 3])
);
console.log(map.get(arrKey));
```

(but this is a pretty ugly thing to have to do - if you find yourself having to do this, *usually* it'd be better to use a different data structure)

Answer (score 0):

You need the same object reference for getting the value from a `Map`.

If you like to use a starting part of the array as key, you need to get all keys from the map and check against with the new array.

```js
var map = new Map,
    key0 = [0, 1, 2, 3],
    key1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];

map.set(key0, "I am some number");
console.log(map.get(key0)); // "I am some number"

for (let key of map.keys())
    if (key.join('|') === key1.join('|'))
        console.log(map.get(key));
```